# Is an f1 micro instance used with kubernetes engine still free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently have an f1 micro instance that I use for PiHole + VPN and it's perfectly adequate for that, I just don't want to be bothered with having to maintain the VM anymore.

I'm looking at switching to Kubernetes engine with a single f1 micro instance and am wondering if that will still be within the free tier allowance. In theory it should since GKE gives 1 free cluster and f1 micro is free, but the GCP calculator shows it as $3.88/month.

Does anyone know the answer to this, or do I just have to take the plunge and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**You cannot run the `Kubernetes Engine` on `f1-micro` machines.**

---

I suppose you used [Google Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to estimate your costs. The problem is that as said above it's not possible. Let me explain:

`f1-micro` has **0.2 vCPU and 0.6GB of RAM**. It will be important later.

If you would try to create `GKE` cluster with single `f1-micro` type of machine you would stumble upon message that `f1-micro` needs at least 3 nodes in `default-pool`:

[image: GCP1]

Even if you try to change the number of nodes to 3 and create your cluster you will get a message on the top of `GCP Dashboard`:

[image: GCP DASHBOARD]

Please let me know if you have any questions in that.

Additionally please take a look on this GKE pricing link: [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) which entails changes in `GKE` pricing from 6th of June 2020.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Dawid! I had looked at the pricing page and the limtis documentation and there is no mention of a 3-node minimum or exclusions of f1 micro instances on either page, so thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @Wuubb 3 node minimum requirement is only showing for `f1-micro`. You can create a `GKE` cluster with a 1 node but with for example `n1-standard`. Also please take in consideration that cluster smaller than 3 nodes may experience downtimes during upgrades.